# Yet another (13)Permission denied error on Apache2 server

Tags: virtualhost, ubuntu-10.04, apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I just can't figure it out. I'm running apache2 on a Ubuntu 10.04 i386 server. Whenever I visit my server (has an IP address, and is connected to internet with static IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) so that's not the problem) in browser, **mysub.domain.edu** (renamed here), I get the following:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server
```

The apache2 error log confirms this:

```
[Mon Apr 18 02:38:20 2011] [error] [client zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

**I'll try to provide all necessary information below:**

1) Contents of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

2) Contents of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin email@domain.com

DocumentRoot /home/myusername/htdocs
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
<Directory "/home/myusername/htdocs/">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
order allow,deny
allow from all
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Satisfy any
</Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
ServerName mysub.domain.edu

</VirtualHost>
```

3) Contents of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin email@domain.com

DocumentRoot /home/myusername/htdocs
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
<Directory "/home/myusername/htdocs/">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
order allow,deny
allow from all
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Satisfy any
</Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all 
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
ServerName mysub.domain.edu

</VirtualHost>
```

4) Result of ls -l (when I'm using sudo -i to be root):

```
root@myserver:/home/myusername# ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root 4096 2011-04-18 03:04 htdocs
```

5) ps auxwww | grep -i apache

```
root@myserver:/home# ps auxwww | grep -i apache
root     15121  0.0  0.4   5408  2544 ?        Ss   16:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15122  0.0  0.3   5180  1760 ?        S    16:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15123  0.0  0.5 227020  2788 ?        Sl   16:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15124  0.0  0.5 227020  2864 ?        Sl   16:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     29133  0.0  0.1   3320   680 pts/0    R+   16:58   0:00 grep --color=auto -i apache
```

6) ls -al /home/myusername/htdocs/

```
root@myserver:/# ls -al /home/myusername/htdocs/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data   root       4096 2011-04-18 03:04 .
drw-r--r-- 4 myusername myusername 4096 2011-04-18 02:13 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root         69 2011-04-18 02:14 index.html
```

I'm not currently using any .htaccess files in my web root (htdocs) folder in my user folder.

I don't know what is wrong, I've been trying to fix his for over 12 hours and I've gotten nowhere. If you have any suggestions, I'm all ears...

Comment: I assume you've tried reloading the apache conf?

Comment: no, I haven't. do you mean just starting over from a blank /etc/apache2/apache2.conf? this is literally all I have in the file


`DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`

Comment: Can you also post the output of `ls -al /home/myusername/htdocs/`? Also the output of `ps auxwww | grep -i apache` to confirm apache is running as www-data. Finally, are you sure www-data can cd into /home/myusername? It needs to do that in order to reach htdocs. Post `ls -al /home` if in doubt.

Comment: @eduardo i.
done, it should be in the updated section

also what is the -al flag?

Comment: nevermind, that's used to find out what user owns the folder. thanks a bunch though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your /home/username and /home has the permissions 755

EDITL: I'll add onto here so its easier to read

You posted this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data   root       4096 2011-04-18 03:04 .
drw-r--r-- 4 myusername myusername 4096 2011-04-18 02:13 ..
```

As you can see the /home/myusername folder has rw, r , r. You need to give "x" to that folder and the /home folder

```
chmod o+x /home
chmod o+x /home/myusername
```

Comment: `root@myserver:/home/myusername# ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root 4096 2011-04-18 03:04 htdocs`

Comment: Your problem is right here:
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data   root       4096 2011-04-18 03:04 .
drw-r--r-- 4 myusername myusername 4096 2011-04-18 02:13 ..

The folder above your htdocs folder (i.e your home directory) has the wrong permissions. You need the "x" permisson on both /home and /home/myusername because that is needed to traverse through the directory

Run the command chmod o+x /home/myusername

Comment: wow! that fixes it. I thought that www-data would only need +x on the htdocs folder...why does it need +x on home?

Comment: Its because the www-data user needs to go through both folders, without x on the upper folders it never gets to htdocs

Answer (score 2):

(this is more of a debugging suggestion, as I think that Pratik has answered the question with the +x)

The error you mention is a file system permission error, so unless your apache config file is redirecting/aliasing onto some restricted place in the file system, then your problem is with the permissions on the /home/myusername/htdocs
 directory, or the index.html file.

In order to see where your apache user is being denied, run the following command;

```
su -s /bin/bash apache
```

and then attempt to

```
cd /home/myusername/htdocs
```

Answer (score 1):

BEWARE of bad advice about permissions.  Generally you should NOT put 755 on your /home/username directory.

The correct permissions are documented in the httpd.conf file and I will paste the pertinent sections here:

```
# This usually means that ~userid  (/home/username for the lay person)
# must have permissions of 711
```

NOTE 711 on ~userid is recommended, please AVOID 755 for /home/username ( ~userid )!!!!!!!!  ,

```
#~userid/public_html must have permissions"
# of 755"
```

~userid/public_html is ok to give 755, but if you give 755 to your ~userid folder EVERYONE on your system will be able to access your home folder and read your files and execute files in home, generally really BAD practice on a multi-user system.  711 avoids giving out read access to group and other

Comment: It might be worth explaining *exactly* what extra permission 755 gives a malicious user on your system compared to 711.  The word *access* is rather vague and could be considered true for everything between 711 and 777.  You could also explain what 711 still allows... for instance if you drop a world-readable `privatekey.pem` in your home directory, can the malicious user still read it if your home directory has mode 711?

Comment: 711 on the home folder grants rwx on owner, folder navigation but no file access at all for group and other. It is the minimum access required for UserDir to work, allows apache to navigate without file access.  It is recommended in this case

Answer (score 0):

I would always start with copying your configs into your home directory and 'apt-get purge apache2'.

Then re-install it and do a 'diff -y oldfile newfile' to see the changes. If bizarrely it's not configuration changes then it's permissions on your web root directory.

It'll only take a couple of minutes unless you have lots of vhosts.